# Wait for Document.Reload in Word VSTO

Tags: ms-word, async-await, vsto

I am calling, `document.Reload()` in an event in VSTO plugin for Word.

Now, microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.reload?view=vsto-2017) says,

> This method reloads the document asynchronously.

but this function isn't declared ***async***,

So, how can I ***await*** for completion of this function's execution, cz else my code proceeds with further execution and an exception is generated as that particular document is unloaded at that moment.

Here is the snippet from my code, I had handled **AfterSave** event,

```
public async void Application_DocumentAfterSave(Word.Document Doc, XMLValue newXMLValue = null) {
     //Some code

     Doc.Reload();

     //Some more code

     var fullNameOfDoc = Doc.FullName;
     //Here I am getting an exception as 
     //System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Object has been deleted.'
}
```

Comment: Can you post enough code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: What's the origin of the document and why are you re-loading? Reading the documentation, this method is intended for documents opened via a hyperlink...

Comment: It is local document only, I am using this function because when you compare 2 documents and save it sometimes it doesn't show path of document in Info section of File menu, so post reload it works as expected, but this leading to some newer problems

Comment: `async-await` isn't the only asynchronous programming pattern. It's just the latest. Maybe there's an event you subscribe to.

Comment: Yup, if there is some event I can subscribe to it would be best.